# Android RSSI value of Bluetooth returns -32768 always?

Tags: android, bluetooth, onclick, rssi, signal-strength

I am trying to get the current RSSI value of a connected bluetooth device at the click of a button. However it returns only -32768 always! Don't know what is wrong! However I was able to get the correct RSSI, the first time it got connected.

```
private Button.OnClickListener buttonRSSIOnClickListener = new Button.OnClickListener(){
  @Override
  public void onClick(View arg0) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   Intent intent = new Intent(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
   short rssi = intent.getShortExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_RSSI,Short.MIN_VALUE);
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"  RSSI: " + rssi + "dBm", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

  }};
```

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 9):

This isn't how you use an Intent.  You are getting -32768 because the RSSI isn't in that Intent that you just created, and the default result you have specified is Short.MIN_VALUE (-32768).

You need to subclass BroadcastReceiver, and create an IntentFilter (or use the manifest) to so that you receive the BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND intent.

You won't be able to do this "at the click of a button."  You'll only get it when Android generates the ACTION_FOUND.

Here is something close.  Haven't run it myself.

In onCreate():

```
registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND));
```

Elsewhere:

```
private final BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        String action = intent.getAction();
        if(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
            short rssi = intent.getShortExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_RSSI,Short.MIN_VALUE);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"  RSSI: " + rssi + "dBm", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
};
```

EDIT: Actually you might be able to do it on-demand if you call startDiscovery() on your BluetoothAdapter from within onClick().  That should trigger ACTION_FOUND for each device it discovers.

Comment: receiver not working...instead when i did filter for RSSI, then lib classes print log on "onScanResult"...any idea how can get result RSSI result for connected device..?