# Android distance between devices (very accurate)

Tags: android, bluetooth, gps, location

I am building an application that requires to check when is a certain device very close to another device (by very close i mean 5-10 meters). I think it could be possible using bluetooth RSSI. A lot of people suggest the use of sound analysis, but this won't be possible because i am planning to use many systems like this in the same place, so that will mess up a bit. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Accuracy requirements rules GPS out -  so your only option is to measure delays in signal propagation of devices. I would  say that network / bluetooth is not suitable for this due to speed of light and network stack delays which are not predictable.   This means that yout only option will be sound.   5-10 meter means 10-20 msec delay  at speed of sound  so this should be sufficient, buit will be tricky to imlpement.

To work with multiple devices you will have to implement some protocol like CSMACD and kind of time synchronisation between devices -  this is possible but tricky ( you will have to look up how time is synchronized via satellites  for radioastronomy )

Comment: I would much prefer doing this with bluetooth signal strength, is that possible?

Comment: Well, you will get something but I doubt that you will get any precision with it.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using RSSI :-). This makes sense if you want to measure the distance b/w 5-10 meters.

Comment: please check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7169653/android-rssi-value-of-bluetooth-returns-32768-always